# How to monitor the process of Neural Network Learning

Tags: performance-tuning, dynamic, machine-learning, neural-networks

## Main Problem

I'm exploring the neural network in v11 and I would like to monitor the training progress in my own way instead of Mathematica's default way. So my question is, how to do this **conveniently**?

---

## Example to try

So now I want to train a classifier on a set of points:

```
trainset = #1 -> {#2} & @@@ 
   Flatten[Thread[
       Rest[AnglePath[# Pi, Table[1./t^(2/3), {t, 1, 200}]]] -> 
        2 # - 1] & /@ {0, 1}, 1];
```

and I would like to get a result like：

[image: img1]

Where the small points are data points and color represents classification.

It's easy to write the code implementing basic form of neural network training to accomplish this：

```
net = NetInitialize@
   NetChain[{DotPlusLayer[20, 2], Tanh, 20, Tanh, 20, Tanh, 20, Tanh, 
     1, Tanh}];

net = NetTrain[net, trainset, MaxTrainingRounds -> 2500];

Show[ContourPlot[net[{x, y}][[1]], {x, -40, 40}, {y, -40, 40}, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][(#/2 + 1)/2] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
 ListPlot[Style[#[[1]], 
     ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][(#[[2, 1]] + 1)/2]] & /@ trainset, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]]
```

However, I would like to monitor the whole learning process, so this is what I've tried: splitting the whole learning process into pieces, then use Dynamic to track them.

```
Dynamic[Show[
  ContourPlot[net[{x, y}][[1]], {x, -40, 40}, {y, -40, 40}, 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][(#/2 + 1)/2] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
  ListPlot[Style[#[[1]], 
      ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][(#[[2, 1]] + 1)/2]] & /@ trainset]], TrackedSymbols :> {net}]

Do[net = NetTrain[net, trainset, MaxTrainingRounds -> 100], {30}];
```

This piece of code will produce a pretty good dynamic result, but there's two main problems inside it. Solving any of them will be quite helpful:

1. The default tracker keeps bumping out and is quite annoying. How to close the default tracker and stop it from showing up? are there any options that can do this job?
2. As you can see, keep re-initializing the `NetTrain` process can slow down the whole calculation a lot. So are there any way to do this job without `NetTrain` for multiple times?(Note that it will be a much better answer if anyone solved this!)

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Could you define: "default tracker", "bumping out and influence", "notebooks order"?

Comment: Default tracker means the small window showing you the progress, loss rate and loss-step curve. As for "Bumping out", I edit it a bit, I just don't want to see the default tracker bumping out.

Comment: To turn off the training progress panel, pass `"ShowTrainingProgress" -> False` as an option to `NetTrain`

Comment: @Wjx Sorry for confusion, I have Print To Console by default and I haven't seen that default tracker at all. Messages window wasn't opened automatically.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can pass the undocumented option `"ShowTrainingProgress" -> False` to turn off the training progress blob thing.

As for monitoring the progress yourself, there is a feature coming in 11.1 called `Checkpointing` that lets you specify a callback to every so often that gets access to the partially trained net. You WOULD use it like so:

```
NetTrain[
   ..., 
   Checkpointing -> <|
      "Interval" -> Quantity[5, "Rounds"], 
       "Function" -> f
   |>
]
```

where f will be called on the partial networks every 5 training rounds. There's other units like `"Seconds", "Minutes", "Hours"`, and `"Batches"`. And you can also save the partially trained networks to a directory using a different suboption (they get named uniquely).

This is actually all implemented already, and lets you do interesting visualizations, like the following of the Lena "Neat Example" you can find in the `NetTrain` documentation:

[animation of lena training](https://imgur.com/a/KUXe6)

Comment: May I ask how you guys find out those undocumented options? Well well, you are seemingly working in Wolfram, so that's not a problem~ Thank you very much!

Comment: @Wjx: Options@NetTrain

Comment: Oh, yeah, This is of couse a way. I usually simply go over the documentation and forget this. Thanks! But Even with this we won't be able to know about `Checkpointing` ~ :P

Comment: The option Checkpointing is already implemented but is not part of the 11.0.0. Right? For now ( version 11.0.0) it is not possible to get the loss values as a function of the Batches? Or save the partially trained networks?

Comment: @lgmendes no, it'll come in 11.1. But there is an internal way to get out the loss history as a simple list after you have trained, one loss per batch: `NeuralNetworks\`$LastLossHistory`. If you specified a ValidationSet you can get those losses out too with  `NeuralNetworks\`$LastValidationLossHistory`.

Comment: The timeframe for the release of the version 11.1 will be weeks or months? The capabilities of version 11.0.1 for doing the analysis of the performance of the training, validation and test of the networks is limited.

Comment: It's months, but not 6 months. The new progress monitoring we've got running on 11.1 builds is already much, much better, and gives you access to a whole goody-bag of functionality.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon Any chance you can push all these into a new prerelease of 11.1 soon? NetTrain doesn't work at all with the current prerelease. Also it would be nice if we could use PredictorMeasurements on nets (like ClassifierMeasurements).